Separate DataGrids bound to same Observable Collection
I have a WPF application with a TabControl and on two different TabItems I want to display the same content in a DataGrid on each.  The order of operations is as follows:

User selects a signal or range of signals from a ListBox and adds it to the first DataGrid which is on the same tab.  This same signal is added to the 2nd DataGrid on another tab which is then used for selecting which signals in that DataGrid to add to a LiveGraph.

I've done some research and have seen many posts about similar issues but I have also found this post which most closely matches what I am trying to do, but it still doesn't work for me.
Originally, I had made the mistake of directly binding both DataGrid ItemsSource to the same ObservableCollection which resulted in the following exception being raised:  "InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."
So following the link above I added two ListCollectionViews and bound them to each DataGrid but this same exception is still being raised when the application first starts up.  I have also tried setting different modes on the ItemsSource bindings without success.
One thing that stands about the post above that I followed is that the DataGrids on that post do not declare an ItemsSource in the Xaml but it is done in the code behind. I assumed that my binding to the Observables would also work.
If anyone could help me figure out what detail I'm missing here that would be great and I would really appreciate it.
Here is the first DataGrid declaration:
<DataGrid
    x:Name="PeekActionsDataGrid"
    Width="auto"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    BorderBrush="Black"
    BorderThickness="1"
    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
    GridLinesVisibility="None"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    IsEnabled="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding PeekSignalCollectionView}"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="true"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>

Here is the second DataGrid declaration:
<DataGrid
    x:Name="GraphSignalDataGrid"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    Grid.Column="2"
    Width="auto"
    MinWidth="50"
    MinHeight="50"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    BorderBrush="Black"
    BorderThickness="1"
    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
    GridLinesVisibility="None"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    IsEnabled="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding PeekGraphCollectionView}"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="true"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>

Here are the MVVM ToolKit items I am using in the code behind to make them visible to the View from the ViewModel:
    // holds the dictionary signals selected by the user 
    [ObservableProperty] public static RangeObservableCollection<EcwsPeekSignalModel>? _peekSignalsList = new();
    // trying to use the list above in two different datagrids on two separate tab items
    [ObservableProperty] private ListCollectionView _peekSignalCollectionView = new(_peekSignalsList);
    [ObservableProperty] private ListCollectionView _peekGraphCollectionView = new(_peekSignalsList);

**Update - Reproducible Code **
Using the example provided by @Sir Rufo I have stripped out the parts of my application which reproduces this issue.
MainWindow.xaml
<Window
x:Class="DataGridBindingProblem.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:DataGridBindingProblem.ViewModels"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="800"
Height="450"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<DockPanel>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Var. 1">
            <DataGrid
                Grid.Column="0"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding PeekSignalList}">
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="auto"
                    Binding="{Binding SignalName}"
                    Header="Signal Name"
                    IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <!--<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />-->
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCyan" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <!--<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />-->
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Var 2">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding PeekSignalList}">
                <!--
                    Here is where the problem occurs.  In my application the xaml parser isn't
                    providing me with too much info but in this new project it says that the
                    itemsource is in use and to use ItemsControl instead but I am not sure how
                    to do that with a datagrid in this situation.
                -->
                <DataGridTextColumn
                    Width="auto"
                    Binding="{Binding SignalName}"
                    Header="Signal Name"
                    IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <!--<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />-->
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightCyan" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <!--<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />-->
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>

MainViewModel.cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using DataGridBindingProblem.Models;

using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

using DataGridBindingProblem.Models;

namespace DataGridBindingProblem.ViewModels
{
    public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty] private RangeObservableCollection<EcwsPeekSignalModel> _peekSignalList;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            PeekSignalList = new();

            PeekSignalList.Add(new("Signal1"));

            PeekSignalList.Add(new("Signal2"));
        }
    }
}

EnumTypes.cs
namespace DataGridBindingProblem.CustomTypes
{
    public enum FccIdEnumType
    {
        LA = 0,   
        LB,    
        RA,    
        RB,     
    }

    public enum SignalDataTypeEnumType
    {
        FLOAT = 0,
        SIGNED,
        UNSIGNED,
    }
}

EcwsPeekSignalModel.cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using DataGridBindingProblem.CustomTypes;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace DataGridBindingProblem.Models
{
    public partial class EcwsPeekSignalModel : ObservableObject
    {

        #region constructors

        /* no defeault constructor a signal must at least have a name */
        public EcwsPeekSignalModel(string? signalName)
        {
            // current values
            _signalName = signalName;
            _laCurrentValue = "--";
            _lbCurrentValue = "--";
            _raCurrentValue = "--";
            _rbCurrentValue = "--";

            // last values
            LaLastValue = "--";
            LbLastValue = "--";
            RaLastValue = "--";
            RbLastValue = "--";

            LaLogList = new();
            LbLogList = new();
            RaLogList = new();
            RbLogList = new();
        }

        #endregion constructors

        // Used to create records for logging
        public void AddLogEntry(int? logTime,
                                        FccIdEnumType? sLane,
                                        string? sVal,
                                        int? rNum, bool? recordFlag = false)
        {
            switch(sLane)
            {
                case FccIdEnumType.LA:
                {
                    LaLastValue = LaCurrentValue;
                    LaCurrentValue = sVal;

                    // only create a log entry if recording is true
                    if(recordFlag == true)
                    {
                        // store the current value as history
                        LaLogList?.Add(new SignalLogEntry(logTime, sLane, sVal, rNum));
                    }

                    break;
                }
                case FccIdEnumType.LB:
                {
                    LbLastValue = LbCurrentValue;
                    LbCurrentValue = sVal;

                    // only create a log entry if recording is true
                    if(recordFlag == true)
                    {
                        // store the current value as history
                        LbLogList?.Add(new SignalLogEntry(logTime, sLane, sVal, rNum));
                    }

                    break;
                }
                case FccIdEnumType.RA:
                {
                    RaLastValue = RaCurrentValue;
                    RaCurrentValue = sVal;

                    // only create a log entry if recording is true
                    if(recordFlag == true)
                    {
                        // store the current value as history
                        RaLogList?.Add(new SignalLogEntry(logTime, sLane, sVal, rNum));

                    }
                    break;
                }
                case FccIdEnumType.RB:
                {
                    RbLastValue = RbCurrentValue;
                    RbCurrentValue = sVal;

                    // only create a log entry if recording is true
                    if(recordFlag == true)
                    {
                        // store the current value as history
                        RbLogList?.Add(new SignalLogEntry(logTime, sLane, sVal, rNum));

                    }
                    break;
                }
                case null:
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // clears the log list and resets values
        public void ClearLogLists()
        {
            RemoveSignal = false;

            LaCurrentValue = "--";
            LbCurrentValue = "--";
            RaCurrentValue = "--";
            RbCurrentValue = "--";

            LaLastValue = LaCurrentValue;
            LbLastValue = LbCurrentValue;
            RbLastValue = RaCurrentValue;
            RaLastValue = RaCurrentValue;

            LaLogList?.Clear();
            LbLogList?.Clear();
            RaLogList?.Clear();
            RbLogList?.Clear();
        }

        #region LogLists

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        private List<SignalLogEntry>? _laLogList;

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        internal List<SignalLogEntry>? LaLogList { get => _laLogList; set => _laLogList = value; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        private List<SignalLogEntry>? _lbLogList;

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        internal List<SignalLogEntry>? LbLogList { get => _lbLogList; set => _lbLogList = value; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        private List<SignalLogEntry>? _raLogList;

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        internal List<SignalLogEntry>? RaLogList { get => _raLogList; set => _raLogList = value; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        private List<SignalLogEntry>? _rbLogList;

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        internal List<SignalLogEntry>? RbLogList { get => _rbLogList; set => _rbLogList = value; }

        #endregion LogLists

        #region jsonProperties


        //public string? SignalName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(Order = 1, PropertyName = "")]
        [ObservableProperty] private string? _signalName;

        #endregion jsonProperties

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        [ObservableProperty] private SignalDataTypeEnumType? _signalDataType;

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        [ObservableProperty] private bool? _removeSignal;

        // variables for historical data used when expBorting the log data
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        [ObservableProperty] private string? _laCurrentValue;
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        [ObservableProperty] private string? _lbCurrentValue;
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        [ObservableProperty] private string? _raCurrentValue;
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        [ObservableProperty] private string? _rbCurrentValue;

        // variables for historical data used when exporting the log data
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        [ObservableProperty] private string? _laLastValue;
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        [ObservableProperty] private string? _lbLastValue;
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        [ObservableProperty] private string? _raLastValue;
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore]
        [ObservableProperty] private string? _rbLastValue;
    }
}

SignalLogEntry.cs
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace DataGridBindingProblem.CustomTypes
{
    internal class SignalLogEntry
    {
        /* since this is a log entry I do not want to allow a default constructor
         * a logentry must have these items
         */
        private int? _rtcTime;
        private FccIdEnumType? _signalLane;
        private string? _signalValue;
        private int? _runNUm;

        [SetsRequiredMembers]
        public SignalLogEntry(int? rtc, FccIdEnumType? sLane, string? sVal, int?rNum)
        {
            _rtcTime = rtc;
            _signalLane = sLane;
            _signalValue = sVal;
            _runNUm = rNum;
        }

        // returns an array of strings for logging to excel
        public string[] GetLogArray()
        {
            return new string[] { $"{_rtcTime}", 
                $"{_signalValue}"};
        }

        public int? GetRtcTime()
        {
            return _rtcTime;
        }

        public FccIdEnumType? GetSignalLane()
        {
            return _signalLane;
        }

        public string? GetValue()
        {
            return _signalValue;
        }

        // returns a string representation of this log entry objects values
        public string GetLog()
        {
            return $"'{_rtcTime},{_signalValue},";
        }

        public int? GetLogEntryTime()
        {
            return _rtcTime;
        }

        public int? GetRunNum()
        {
            return (int?) _runNUm;
        }
    }
}

RangeObservableCollection.cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace DataGridBindingProblem.Models
{
    public class RangeObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        private bool _suppressNotification = false;

        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_suppressNotification == false)
            {
                base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
            }
        }

        public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            if (list == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("list");           
            }
                

            _suppressNotification = true;

            foreach (T item in list)
            {
                Add(item);
            }
            _suppressNotification = false;

            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }
}

So I have found where it occurring but am unsure of how to approach fixing it.  When AutoGenerateColumns is true and the DataGrid TextColumns are removed the app runs but I don't need all of the autogenerated columns in either table.

I cannot reproduce it https://gist.github.com/SirRufo/39b5903c8adc116e962572405b5c8af2

You can bind as many ItemControls to a collection as you like. The exception is thrown because you somewhere modify (add/remove/clear/move) the ItemsControl via the ItemsControl.Items property, which is illegal when the returned collection view was created from the ItemsSource value.

@SirRufo thanks for the link.  In my XAML I was setting the DataContext of the MainView to the MainViewModel.  In yours you are doing that in the code behind as well as creating an object of MainViewModel.  When I tried mimicking the rest of your example I did not see the values in the first DataGrid show up in the second but I think I will work on refactoring with this new DataContext and then see what happens.    I will update the post when I finish and have more results.  Thanks!

@MichaelRiley That does not matter at all. I checked that too

@SirRufo yes you are correct.  I also downloaded and modified your solution and it works but mine still does not.

@BionicCode Yes I see what you are saying.  In my code when only the first DataGrid existed I do perform Clear on the PeekSignalList but at form load the only thing I do is instantiate the PeekSignalList with new().  The exception says to ". Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead" so I am confused as to whether that refers to the code behind or in XAML.  The second DataGrid only needs the data contained within the PeekSignal list  wont modify it.  I tried changing the second one to have  but no joy there either

If you call clear directly on the source collection then you are doing it correctly. You can't call ItemsControl.Items.Clear.  Also don't create the extra overhead of registering those ListCollectionViews unless you need to sort/filter each collection view independently. Would you mind posting a minimal reproducible example, please? This way we can review your code. It's difficult to impossible to guess where you went wrong. The XAML is really not enough. The XAML isn't even very relevant here. It's more interesting how you handle the collection and collection views.

It would be great if you can also show the line of code that throws the exception. Exception message and context should always be provided if you seek help. The point is we don't know anything about your implementation details.

@BionicCode question updated as requested.  Apologies for the delay

Thanks for providing the example. Now I can properly review your code.

After reviewing your code I found an error in your markup.
You have two options to populate an ItemsControl:

using the ItemsSource property
or using the Items property

The ItemsControl can't handle both options, so you have to decide for one way otherwise the XAML parser will throw the exception that you have posted:

"InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead."
important to know that you can't

You can add items to the ItemsControl.Items property in XAML too by using collection syntax and the content property (ItemsControl has the Items property defined as the content property):
<ListBox>
  <ListBoxItem />
</ListBox>

Because the content property is ItemsControl.Items the ListBoxItem of the preceding example is implicitly added to the ListBox.Items property.
This is exactly what you did (probably by accident):
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding PeekSignalList}"> <!-- ItemsSource is used... -->
  <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto"
                      Binding="{Binding SignalName}"
                      Header="Signal Name"
                      IsReadOnly="True"> <!-- ...At the same time, this object is added to the Items property -->
  </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid>

At the same time, you are binding the DataGrid.ItemsSource which causes the XAML parser to throw.
However, the item container of the DataGrid is the DataGridRow. Therefore, the preceding XAML is semantically wrong in that you were adding DataGridColumn objects to the Items property (instead of DataGridRow objects).
If you weren't using the ItemsSource property the correct XAML would be as follows:
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGridRow />
</DataGrid>

However, the point is that DataGridColumn objects must be added to the DataGrid.Columns collection. It doesn't make sense to add them to the Items collection as they are not item containers (I assume this happend by accident, somehow). They are only layout elements that tell the DataGrid how the table is structured.
The fixed XAML looks as follows:
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding PeekSignalList}">
  <DataGrid.Columns> <!-- Add DatGridColumns to the DataGrid.Columns collection -->
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="auto"
                        Binding="{Binding SignalName}"
                        Header="Signal Name"
                        IsReadOnly="True">
    </DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>


@BionicCode...My friend I really appreciate the time and effort to clarify this for me.  When I originally utilized the first DataGrid it was about 8 months ago and had not used one before.  So you were very correct that a cut and paste or some other accident happened but it worked so I left it behind.  Looking at your solution to my issue I can absolutely see and agree with it.  Thanks again!

Hi Michael, I'm happy I could help. And thank you very much for your appreciation and kind words! Thanks. Have a great day!
